# How do I know port of device for Android USB debugging?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, port

I understand that port forwarding is now a built in part of Chrome but I still can't get it to work right.

I am trying to access my computers localhost through a usb connected Android device. I can debug fine on the world wide web, but I need to do some phone debugging of things on my local machine.

The port forwarding dialog box suggests I need to map my computers localhost to a port on my device.

I can't for the life of me figure out the port my device is running on.

How do I get my device properly mapped to my localhost running on 127.0.0.1?